# Coded Smilies in SE Chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

Although the audience in the chat rooms of SE sites are generally different from sites like , say, Facebook. You usually just don't chat about unrelated random stuff in SE chat rooms (with the possible exception of [`Lounge<C++>`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec), that room is awesome!) but still I sometimes do feel the need of coded smilies. Like those in Facebook Chat, Chatango etc. (you know , type **:)** for a smile, **:(** for a sad face etc.)

Can the developers please include this feature in SE Chat soon?

Comment: What's wrong with textual ones?

Comment: @simchona nothing, but pictures just look a bit better. :)

Comment: Rule of thumb: If it's a feature Facebook has, we probably don't want it.

Comment: So it doesn't really fix anything or add anything? I don't think I'd want the developers trying to implement that.

Comment: For bonus points, consider rewriting this as a bug report :)

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox No thanks.I've gotten enough points as it is. (4 downvotes). :(

Comment: I find it incredibly offensive when chat/IM programs replace what I *intended* to type (a textual smiley) with some kind of graphic. I *always* turn this off, but I'm still bothered knowing the person on the other end is probably receiving silly animated graphic smilies from me.

Comment: Public Anouncement: Please every one. I get your point! Would you please spare me the little rep. I have left and stop downvoting? Thank You.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: ...get out.]

Comment: +1: if you want a pretty picture, add it yourself.

Comment: @simchona Indeed, [it works well enough.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/821483#821483)

Comment: You just opened a [very big can of worms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/821491#821491).

Answer (score 13):

By means of example, here's an excerpt from today's transcript of the [Super User chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118).

[image]

Thanks, but no thanks.

Comment: God, it's horrible!!! That's it. I'm flagging my own question! Sorry for my request, if any developer is seeing this, please forget what I asked.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker `if any developer is seeing this` You mean other than [balpha](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha)? :P

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox lol, I didn't know [balpha](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) was a SE dev.

Comment: apparently we [su]s  use a lot of smileys. Hmm.

Comment: Oh no, my eyes!